# McGee's argument on restriction of consistent instances of T-schema

Tags: logic, truth, tarski

Could someone help me understand what is McGee's argument on restriction of consistent instances of T-schema about please?

This is gonna be messy so please bear with me.

Halbach and Holsten's *"Norms for Theories of Reflexive Truth"* argues that one of the desiderata of a (formal) theory of truth should be that Tr('ϕ') and ϕ (I am using 'ϕ' to mean the Godel number of ϕ here, since Mathjax doesn't work here) can be substituted salva demonstrabilitate. (I take it this means that given we can prove that ϕ is true, the two are interchangeable)

Halbach and Holsten (H&H) then talk about how we can restrict the class of instances of the T-schema.

**One option is to restrict it to consistent instances, but H&H cite McGee's paper *"Maximal consistent sets of instances of Tarski's Schema T"* and argue that this does not suffice, and I do not understand why McGee's argument shows that.**

H&H argue that McGee shows that with the diagonal lemma every sentence is equivalent to a T-schema. Thus any sentence independent from the base theory can be decided using a consistent instance of the T-schema. (Base theory refers to Peano arithmetic, or PA)

As far as I know, the diagonal lemma states that if theory T satisfies certain properties, and φ(x) is a formula with x being a free variable, then there is a sentence γ such that T⊢γ⟺φ('γ')$. But I don't see how applying this lemma gives us B_ϕ⟺(ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')).

I also don't understand what "any sentence independent from the base theory can be decided using a consistent instance of the T-schema" means, and why it shows that restricting to consistent instances does not work.

I apologise in advance of the messiness of this question, but I am really confused and I've tried my best to state it as best as I could.

---

H&H's argument. (Base theory refers to Peano arithmetic, or PA)
[image]

---

Some preliminaries from McGee's paper, the relevant part is on what S and R mean.
[image]

---

The relevant result from McGee's paper, although I suspect only the first half is relevant. (Theory S refers to some consistent arithmetical theory which entails the axioms of Robinson's R)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Never heard of Robinson's R, are you sure it's not the usual Q?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Yea Q would definitely make more sense, but 'Robinson's R' is what McGee wrote, I can prove the screenshot of the relevant section if you would like to have a look

Comment: Sure, more is of course better... Also I remember you mentioned before in this book McGee used Yablo paradox (assuming it's a real paradox as the liar) to show such desiderata cannot allow for standard interpretation of N, so is this paragraph after that section? Anyway related?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Sure, I've added the screenshot as an edit. As for Yablo's paradox, it was Leitgeb who cited McGee, but that McGee paper is a different one and I haven't read that paper yet

Comment: I see, this is a different paper from Halbach and Holsten talking about similar truth theory desiderata. I see there's a "6" index upon Robinson's R, can you cite the content of that index 6?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Index 6: From Alfred Tarski, Andrzej Mostowski, and Raphael M. Robinson, Undecidable Theories (Amsterdam: North-Holland, 1953), p.53

Comment: So seems McGee is depicting a complete theory of truth S containing Robinson's R which is weaker than his famous D but unlike D, R seems an infinitely axiomatized (via axiom schemes) maximally complete (but very weak and expressivity-limited) theory of arithmetic. So McGee proves a theorem claiming the existence of a maximally consistent set of instances of Tarski's T-schema. But I don't understand why McGee chooses R not Q, since diagonal lemma applies only in Q+...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I guess Q does entail R (I found the book Index 6 was referring to and the theorem on p.53 is about proving that R is a subtheory of Q, among other things), so if we treat S as Q I guess we would be alright?

Comment: Simplified the diagonal lemma says (applied to this language) that for every formula Phi(x) there is a sentence A of L_T (I assume this is the language of arithmetic plus the truth predicate) such that (A⟺ Phi(⌜A⌝)) is provable in PA. To get the B_ϕ⟺(ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')) from this you simply let Phi(x) be the formula (ϕ⟺ Tr(x)), and the result immediately follows by the diagonal lemma.

Comment: @Johannes Ahh ok, so that explains the bit about every sentence in L_T being equivalent to a Tarski biconditional. But could you also help me with what "any sentence independent from the base theory can be decided using a consistent instance of the T-schema" means please? I take it that since McGee's result concerns every sentence in L_T, this can obviously include sentences that are not part of the base theory (PA). But then I fail to understand the rest

Comment: From Tarski et al's paper from p.53 and theorem 9, Robinson's R is also essentially undecidable so diagonal lemma also applies in R (seems R (not PA) is treated as the base theory in McGee's paper while PA is treated as base theory of H&H's paper). The only difference between R and Q is R is a subtheory of Q and thus weaker, and R is also not finitely axiomatizable while Q is. But still curious why McGee didn't choose the usual Q or PA as his base theory (maybe in your paper it mentioned some reason?)... Then for the same reason as rightly hinted from @Johannes, in both McGee's and H&H's...

Comment: ...truth theories any sentence independent from the base theory can be decided using a consistent instance of Tarski's convention-T since it's an easy exercise to finally arrive at ϕ⟺(B_ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')) from above application of diagonal lemma applicable in the combined theory T with its language L_T augmented by T-predicate and other required alphabets or nonlogical symbols independent from PA/R...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Sorry if this sounds really stupid: regarding the "any sentence independent from the base theory", is this referring to ϕ or B_ϕ? It doesn't seem to be B_ϕ because it appears to be just some non-specific sentence (in fact I am not entirely sure what B_ϕ is), whereas ϕ can be any sentence (independent from PA/R). But then if it's ϕ, how is it decidable using the T-schema? The truth predicate applies to B_ϕ, not ϕ?

Comment: And isn't Curry's paradox what McGee used (or at least a technique similar to Curry's) to prove ϕ⟺(B_ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')), instead of being something provable from the biconditional equivalence?

Comment: You're right "any sentence independent from the base theory" refers to ϕ, not B_ϕ. B_ϕ is the fixed point of the diagonal lemma's application B_ϕ⟺(ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')), then it's a standard sentential logic exercise to arrive at ϕ⟺(B_ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ'))... Curry's paradox is not invoked so far here as all above is the legitimate use of diagonal lemma since base theory is PA or R, but clearly the solution B_ϕ is dependent and refer to ϕ which is reminiscent of Curry's paradox, and somewhere in the paper McGee might further explained why his own maximal instances of biconditionals ersatz is not enough...

Comment: And you're also right the truth predicate applies to B_ϕ, not ϕ, and the predicate in diagonal lemma is p(x):=(ϕ⟺Tr(x)), B_ϕ is a fixed point of p(x)... Curry's paradox is not really a paradox in classic logic, it originates as a real paradox from the untyped lambda calculus. When translating expressions from mathematics to lambda calculus, the domain of lambda calculus terms is not always isomorphic to the domain of the mathematical expressions. This lack of isomorphism is the source of Curry's paradox. Finally, once you have ϕ⟺(B_ϕ⟺Tr('B_ϕ')) then clearly ϕ is decidable from B_ϕ⟺Tr('B_ϕ')...

Comment: Btw, it can't be the case that someone claiming self-stupidity is stupid. Almost by definition stupidity is the case that one is not feeling or claiming worried/confused when one really doesn't understand or actually confused about something. Dumbness almost by definition describes the one who even doesn't feel or know one is actually constantly confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question was answered in the comments. The short answer to the second is that they assume that the reader can figure out how the truth about there being many incompatible maximal consistent ways to extend PA with T-bivalences follows once it has been pointed out that PA proves that for every φ in L_T, there is an equivalent T-bivalence_φ, plus they give the reference that explains it in detail.

What's going on in this passage more generally:

The authors are discussing the problem faced by those wanting to develop an untyped truth theory, namely, that the theory containing PA + all instances of the T-bivalence without restriction, is inconsistent.

One proposed way to answer this (by Paul Horwich) is to include as many T-bivalence instances as possible retaining consistency (i.e. "maximal consistent" set). However the authors refer to McGee's paper that shows, for one, that there are great many such sets that are maximal consistent (with PA) but mutually incompatible. So the maximal consistency answer as such doesn't give us enough guidance.

(They also note that Cieśliński showed that restriction to a maximal conservative set suffers from similar problems.)

They point to the key fact contained in the proof that illustrates some of the problems in deciding which consistent T-bivalences to allow. As said, applying the diagonal lemma they show that for any sentence φ of L_T, PA proves that φ and some T-bivalence instance are equivalent (call this instance **T-bivalence_φ**).

I assume that they are trying to illustrate that while for some cases of φ, the question whether or not to include the respective T-bivalence_φ is unproblematic (e.g. when φ is inconsistent with PA, so is the T-bivalence_φ, and it should therefore not be included), in other cases the consistency criterion doesn't give us the answer.

In particular they point out that in cases where φ is independent from PA (i.e. PA doesn't prove either φ or not-φ, i.e. doesn't "decide" φ), we get a consistent extension of PA with PA+φ and with PA+not-φ, and so we also get a consistent extension by PA+T-bivalence_φ and with PA+T-bivalence_not-φ. Which of these should we choose? The section [4.1](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2020/entries/truth-axiomatic/#TypeFreeTSent) of the SEP article that discusses this issue mentions a drastic case, a false arithmetical statement φ that is independent of PA, so there are sets of T-bivalences consistent with PA that prove false arithmetical statements.

Comment: I must be retarded...I can see that if there are many mutually exclusive, yet consistent sets of T-schema, this shows that restricting T-schema to consistent ones does not help us. But I just cannot for the life of me figure out how McGee/Holbach&Holsten's proof show this. I read the paragraph in H&H's paper immediately after the proof, but that only seems to be a discussion of what follows from the proof, not how one goes from the proof to the conclusion of there being mutually exclusive, yet consistent T-schema...

Comment: The sentence 'Given an arithmetical sentence (i.e., a sentence not containing T) that can neither be proved nor disproved in PA, one can find a consistent T-sentence that decides this sentence. This implies that many consistent sets of T-sentences prove false arithmetical statements.' from the SEP is the closest 'explanation' I can find, but again I don't see how having a sentence non-decidable in PA leads to the conclusion that many consistent sets of T-sentences prove false arithmetical statements...

Comment: If sentences φ is independent from PA, then {φ} and {not-φ} are two PA-consistent sets of sentences that are mutually inconsistent. Now in the proof you can let the Δ be either one of these, and as the proof demonstrates for each one you get a maximal consistent set of T-sentences (call them Γ1 and  Γ2) such that Γ1 PA-entails φ, and Γ2 PA-entails not-φ, hence, Γ1 and Γ2 are two maximal PA-consistent sets of T-sentences that are mutually inconsistent. This is enough to bring out the intuition that you can have many such incompatible maximal consistent sets of T-sentences.

Comment: Regarding your "when φ is inconsistent with PA, so is the T-bivalence_φ, and it should therefore not be included", but from OP's quote, the sentence φ is *independent* from the base theory PA thus φ is not inconsistent with PA, so seems to me it's not the main reason why McGee's result is insufficient (having many mutually inconsistent truths is a known feature of coherentism of truth observed and criticized by Russell long ago). OP's quote mentions McGee's attempt is confining to instances that are *conservative* extension of PA (prove no new theorem), and Cieśliński showed this is no better.

Comment: To repeat the both suggestions maximal consistent sets, and maximal concervative sets of T-sentences fail (McGee is concerned with the former, Cieśliński with the latter suggestion) because they don't produce a unique set but an uncountably many possible sets of T-sentences, which are not even recursively axiomatizable. Hence the suggestions are of little comfort to the minimalist.

Comment: I agree the existence of many maximal consistent sets is fine, only insufficient for the minimalists due to non-uniqueness. But still 2 issues here. 1) Since the ground language L_A and and the augmented L_T have only countable alphabets, so from McGee's proof above there're at most countably many such Γ's of T-sentences, it seems cannot be uncountably many? 2) Since McGee starts his proof using sentence φ which is supposed to be *independent* from PA, how one can possibly get a maximal Γ which is a non-conservative extension of PA? How is it possible to prove new theorems in PA?

Comment: 1) Sure consider it a typo, let's just say "too many". 2) McGee doesn't start his proof using an independent φ, it doesn't matter what the set Δ contains and that's the point. Also McGee is not concerned with conservative extensions, the issue is not even mention in the paper, he is ciritizising the maximal consistent suggestion. Cieśliński in turn criticizes the maximal conservative extensions suggestion. Their work is complementary not contradictory.

Comment: Thx for your elaboration. It's interesting that your SEP ref authored by Halbach, Volker  and Leigh also mentioned *McGee (1992) showed that there are uncountably many maximal sets of T-sentences that are consistent with PA*. As for OP's question in this thread from same section in SEP *This implies that many consistent sets of T-sentences prove false arithmetical statements.*, Con(PA) can be such an independent sentence from PA and can be decided true or false in some consistent maximal sets, thus it's a false L_A sentence per Godel. That's why deflationists insist conservative restrictions..

Comment: Sorry just to confirm I get this right: because in McGee's theorem, φ can be any sentence of L_T, therefore there are many possibilities of what this φ is. It may be inconsistent with PA, but it could also be undecidable in PA (i.e. φ and ¬ϕ are not provable in PA), in which case by the theorem we get PA∪{B_ϕ} and PA∪{B_¬ϕ} that are both consistent extension of PA, and thus consistency as a restriction is too weak. Is this right?

Comment: @Constantlyconfused strictly speaking you need to replace your above {B_ϕ} with {B_ϕ⟺ Tr('B_ϕ')} and {B_¬ϕ} with {B_¬ϕ⟺ Tr('B_¬ϕ')}, respectively since these are true T-sentences of Γ. It's easy to envision Γ has no PA-inconsistent sentences such as the Liar sentence, but even Γ is consistent with PA, you're right it may not be unique as reasoned above for the cases where ϕ and ¬ϕ are not provable in PA such as Con(PA). But in this case the axiomatic truth theory Γ obviously decides ϕ via its T-sentence, say decides it's false here, then it's false sentence in PA. So this is a non-conservative

Comment: @Constantly confused Pretty much. And with repeated application of the incompleteness theorem it can be shown that there are infinitely many such mutually incompatible maximal PA-consistent sets of T-sentences. As Double Knot noted SEP says there are uncountably many different sets like that. I guess this is my last comment on the matter.

Comment: @Constantlyconfused (ctn...) extension of PA which deflationism rejects obviously which is becoming popular in the market. So any complete augmented axiomatic theory of truth with base theory incomplete is insufficient and problematic for defaltionists...

Comment: @DoubleKnot and Johannes, thank you so much for both of your help, really appreciate it